# Custom Date Parsing in BlackBerry OS

Tags: java, parsing, date, blackberry, java-me

My problem lies in parsing a custom date string in BlackBerry Java. Java SE provides the class [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which has the ability to parse a String against a given pattern/format.

However, in BlackBerry the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html) class does not contain the method to parse, only format a date into the desired pattern.

I am aware of [HttpDateFormatter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html) which can parse a String, however, it is a strict parser that will only work with three date formats that HTTP has used in the past:

- Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT (RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123)
- Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT (RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036)
- Sun Nov 6 08:49:37 1994 (ANSI C's asctime() format)

I will be parsing date strings coming from the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) in the format:

- "Mon Jun 27 19:32:19 +0000 2011"

Before going away and writing my own error prone date parse, is there any other routes I could investigate?

---

Regards,

Thomas Nadin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as of 7.1, there is no method to parse with a custom format in BB Java API. You should implement your own. I did it long ago using `Calendar`, with the same format as the Java SE API.

Before doing your own one, have a look at OpenSource projects like Joda, Guava or OpenJDK, maybe you can find some "inspiration" there.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the OpenSource project mentions, I will indeed take a look at them. As an alternative to parsing I have decided to return the date as a long from the middle-man web service in use.

Comment: You're welcome. then make sure the backend WS has the same reference for timestamps than Java (1/1/1970, AKA epoch).